# Is monotony preserved under expectation?

Tags: statistics, transformation, expectation

let $X_1 \sim f_1(x)$ and $X_2 \sim f_2(x)$.

Suppose we know that $\mu_1=E(X_1)<E(X_2)=\mu_2$ and let $\nu_1=E(\log(X_1))$ and $\nu_2=E(\log(X_2))$.

Since $\log$ is monotonically increasing, my intuition tells me that $\nu_1 < \nu_2$ but I can't find a convincing result to prove it.

Jensen's inequality says that
$\nu_1 < \log \mu_1$ and $\nu_2 < \log \mu_2$ but it doesn't seem to help with this question.

Are there any conditions under which $\nu_1 < \nu_2$ holds? Or does it always hold and why?

Help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: By $X_i\sim f_i(x)$ do you mean that $f_i$ is a density of $X_i$ (i.e. we are assuming the $X_i$ are continuous random variables)?

Comment: Yes. With $f_1$ and $f_2$ not precisely the same. I know $\nu_1 < \nu_2 $ might not hold for arbitrary $f_i$ but I'm looking for conditions on which it holds and why it does.

For my purpouses $X_i$ are continuous r.v. but the question was meant to be general (if it can be generalized).

Comment: Depends on the professor!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not true.  Let $X_1 = 1$ be a constant random variable, and let $\Pr(X_2 = s/2) = \Pr(X_2 = 2s) = 1/2$.  Then $E(X_1) = 1$, $E(X_2) = 5s/4$, $E(\log(X_1)) = 0$, and $E(\log(X_2)) = \log(s)$.  So this gives a counterexample if $4/5 < s < 1$.  I know your distributions are continuous, not discrete, but a simple modification will work.

Comment: Thank you! This was really helpful. 

Just wondering, would that hold if $f_1$ and $f_2$ were the exact same density function but with different location parameter? i.e. if $f_i = f(x-\mu_i)$ where $\mu_i = E(X_i)$. It holds for the particular case of the lognormal distribution but I don't know if it can be generalized.

Comment: I think in your special case, what you want to happen is true.  It can be done using integration by parts.  I'll try to write up the argument, but I'm kind of busy right now.  Hopefully you can figure it out before I get to write it up.

Comment: Actually your special case is way easier to prove than I first thought.  Suppose we call $X$ the random variable that has density $f(x)$.  Then $X_i = X + \mu_i$.

Comment: So, please correct me I'm wrong,
$\nu_1=E(log(X_1))=E(log(X+\mu_i))=\int log(X+\mu_1)f(x) dx > \int log(X+\mu_2)f(x) dx = E(log(X_2)) = \nu_2 $

Comment: Yes, except you got the inequality the wrong way around.